# Criteria Using the sessions ID to display infomation relevant

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to use a criteria where the sessions user id = PhysioReference (a field in the table) but it doesn't seem to be working? what is the correct way or is there a better way?

its to display information in a table to but only where the person logged in has been assigned that information

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA WHERE IASubmitted= 'no' AND PhysioReference = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']";
```

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * FROM IA WHERE IASubmitted= 'no' AND PhysioReference = ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];`

Comment: sorry that didn't work, how would I correctly use a session as im pretty new to this

Comment: well then, try to echo `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` does it have proper value?

Comment: yes the echo showed the correct ID, Dreamweaver is saying there is an issue with that line of code. do define the value before the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);

this worked in the end

Answer (score 0):

Literal representation (**bad idea**) of what you want would be using [Complex (curly) *in string variable* syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA
      WHERE IASubmitted= 'no' AND PhysioReference = ${_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}";
```

This is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), rather use [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA
      WHERE IASubmitted= 'no' AND PhysioReference = ?";

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] )) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo, yes that's what I wanted but still having an issue, do I need to call upon the $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']